# Extend Ubuntu partition dual booting with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, windows-10

I have a Microsoft Surface Book with DGPU and I am new to Ubuntu.

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10 Pro. I need to make the partition for Ubuntu bigger, because I made it only 30 GB. There is also a swap drive of 7GB -- should I reclaim that memory and if so, How do I?

My attempts thus far:

1. Use Ubuntu live cd 14.04 (and 15.10), "Try Ubuntu", run `gparted`. This does not work, `gparted` will only show me the partition of the USB drive its running on. There is a pull down menu on the right that makes it seem as if you can select other drives, but it only lists the usb drive.
   When I run `sudo fdisk -l`, I can see all the partitions, so I don't know why `gparted` doesn't list them all.
2. Use gparted live usb: First, this would not even load, and then I figured out I have to turn Secure boot off completely. When it does finally load I select one of the 5 options, but nothing happens. The program just hangs.

I have scoured the internet but can't find any help.

My last ditch options are two:

1. Re-install Ubuntu and correctly assign it a bigger partiton : annoying  but doable.
2. In windows, shrink my C volume, and extend the ubuntu partition. From my countless google searches this is supposedly inadvisable.

Can I solve this issue?